# vue $emit child function to more parents

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I have a signup form for clients and a signup form for companies.

Both follow same procedure. First check telephone-number, after receiving SMS and validating telephone-number the rest of the form pops up. With only one the $emit works. How can it work the $emit for both parents?

The validation-form of telephonenumber is a child-component nested in the component with the form. Both on the same in client-signup and company-signup.

```
<div>
<div v-show="!isOpen">
    <Verify-telephone @toggle="toggle($event)" />
</div>
<div v-show="isOpen">
//rest of the form
</div>
```

After validating the verify-telephone in the child it is triggered to close and the other  form with the other inputs opens via $emit.

```
methods: {
checkSMSCode() {
        .then((response) => {
            this.$emit('toggle', false)                                        
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to emit the event to the `$root` and listen to it in both parents:
In child (Verify-telephone.vue or any other component):

```js
methods: {
  checkSMSCode() {
    ...
    .then((response) => {
      this.$root.$emit('toggle', false);    
    }
  })
}
```

In the parent set up a listener to root events:

```js
created: {
  this.$root.$on(‘eventName’, (event) => {
    this.toggle(event);
  });
}
```

Comment: I not understand the solution. It is too cryptic. Sorry for this. It is entirely due to my lack of knowledge.

Comment: @Tichel, I have just edited my post to make the solution more clear

Answer (score 0):

After leaving a post with the same question on the Vue-forum I had to understand that a child component can have only one parent. And not two how would have had it. This made me consider that it was better to made the parent component (telephone verify) with two child components (signup user and signup company). It was all very educational.